# After Zoom Marker's are not exatly on the same point. Custom Map GTA5

Tags: jquery, html, css

I hope i can show you the actuel problem and hope any know a way to solve this.

[image: WithoutZoom Picture]

[Click me if you want to see the map](http://www.webdesign-host.ch/thomas/)

**How To Use?** Set in the left corner one marker and place it into the map. Click the Numpad + key to increase or - for decrease the map. (MaxZoomLevel 8)

All markers are img's and will be append in that box.

```
<div id="MarkerBox"></div>
```

This is what markers look like:

```
<img id="Marker_0" src="images/gelb.png" alt="Map Marker" style="top: 417px; left: 745px; position: absolute;">
```

**zoom.js**

As soon as the map has been enlarged, this function moves all the markers to the new locations. Here is probably the mistake.

```
var markersScallingUp = function()
{
    $("#MarkerBox img").each(function(){
        $(this).css("top", $(this).offset().top * 1.2);
        $(this).css("left", $(this).offset().left * 1.2);
    });
}
```

the same way doing for decrease the position from the markers: (maybe scalling not the best name for i "moveMarkerPosition" bether)

```
var markersScallingDown = function()
{
    $("#MarkerBox img").each(function(){
       $(this).css("top", $(this).offset().top / 1.2);
       $(this).css("left", $(this).offset().left / 1.2);
    });
}
```

Change Map Size and use functions to scalling:

```
    var currentZoomLevel = 0;

    var mapWidth = $("#map").width();
    var mapHeight = $("#map").height();

    $(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which)
    {
                    case 107:   
                        if(currentZoomLevel <= 8){
                            $("#map").focus();  
                            $("#map").width(mapWidth * 1.2);
                            $("#map").height(mapHeight * 1.2);
                            markersScallingUp();
                            mapWidth = $("#map").width();
                            mapHeight = $("#map").height(); 

                            currentZoomLevel++;
                        }
                    break;

                    case 109:   
                        if(currentZoomLevel >= 1){
                            $("#map").focus();
                            $("#map").width(mapWidth / 1.2);
                            $("#map").height(mapHeight / 1.2);  
                            mapWidth = $("#map").width();
                            mapHeight = $("#map").height(); 
                            markersScallingDown();
                            currentZoomLevel--;
                        }
                    break;
                }           
    });
```

In the following image, we see that who we zoom, the markers are not placed exactly in the same place as they were deposited by the user. The larger the zoom the farther away is the marker of the actual target. I'm happy about every incentive!

[image: 4xZoom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're expanding the map image inside the maparea, and then doing some manual scaling with the pixels.

I set the image as the background for 'mapareaid'and used percent instead of pixels for the markers. For the scaling an easier approach is using the scale css function to scale your map and markers.

The html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0036)http://www.webdesign-host.ch/thomas/ -->
<html lang="de"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script src="./CustomMap (GTA5)_files/jquery.min.js.download"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CustomMap (GTA5)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CustomMap (GTA5)_files/index.css">
    <script src="./CustomMap (GTA5)_files/zoom.js.download"></script>
    <script src="./CustomMap (GTA5)_files/setmarker.js.download"></script>
    <script src="./CustomMap (GTA5)_files/jquery.elevatezoom.js.download"></script>
  </head>
  <body cz-shortcut-listen="true">

    <div class="menu" id="menu">    

        <img id="btn1" alt="klickmich" class="menubuttons" src="./CustomMap (GTA5)_files/gruen.png"> <img id="btn2" alt="klickmich" class="menubuttons" src="./CustomMap (GTA5)_files/blau.png"> <img id="btn3" alt="klickmich" class="menubuttons" src="./CustomMap (GTA5)_files/rot.png"> <img id="btn4" alt="klickmich" class="menubuttons" src="./CustomMap (GTA5)_files/gelb.png">     
    </div>
    <div class="container">     
        <div id="mapareaid" class="maparea">    

            <!--<img id="map" class="map" style="width: 4833.54px; height: 2310.94px;" src="./CustomMap (GTA5)_files/map.jpg" alt="Dies ist eine gigantische Map von GTA V. Schade, dass du das nicht sehen kannst.">-->
            <div id="MarkerBox"></div>
            <div id="InfoBox">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Marker Stuff -->

    <div id="InfoBox">
        <div class="infoContainer" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; top: 0px; left: 0px;">

            <div class="strukturContainer">
                <div class="infotitel"><h1>Titel</h1></div>

                <div class="bildcontainer"> 
                    <div class="infobild"></div>
                    <div class="infobild"></div>
                    <div class="infobild"></div>    
                </div>  

                <div class="infobeschreibung"> 
                     <textarea>Gib mir eine informative Information.</textarea>
                </div>      
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>

    <!-- Template to generate InfoBox content -->
    <div class="templateinfobox" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <div class="infoContainer">

            <div class="strukturContainer">
                <div class="infotitel"><h1>Titel</h1></div>

                <div class="bildcontainer"> 
                    <div class="infobild"></div>
                    <div class="infobild"></div>
                    <div class="infobild"></div>    
                </div>  

                <div class="infobeschreibung"> 
                     <textarea>Gib mir eine informative Information.</textarea>
                </div>      
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="werkzeugkiste" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <div class="werkzeugContainer">
            <div class="werkzeug1"></div>
            <div class="werkzeug2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body></html>
```

The css

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container
{
    float: left;
    width: 1365px;  
}

.maparea
{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
    overflow: hidden;
}

.map
{
    height: auto;
}

.menu
{   
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;    
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 100;
}

.menubuttons
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.infoContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

.strukturContainer
{
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.infotitel
{
    float: left;
    width: 346px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.bildcontainer
{
    float: left;
    width: 346px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    z-index: 1;
}

.infobild
{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;   
    z-index: 1;
}


.infobeschreibung
{
    width: 346px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    z-index: 1;
}

textarea
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}


#mapareaid{
    background: url('map.jpg');
    background-size:100%;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
    position: relative;
}

#MarkerBox{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

setmarker.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var halfMarkerSize = 15;

    var currentSelection = 0;
    var pictureArray = ["default.png", "gruen.png", "blau.png", "rot.png", "gelb.png"];

    var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };

    var currentScrollPos = 0;

    var markerCountID = 0;
    var markerID = null;

    var x = -1;
    var y = -1;

    var markerBindClick = function()
    {       
        $("#MarkerBox img").each(function(){
            $(this).off("mousedown").on("mousedown", function(e){
                switch(e.which)
                {
                    case 1:
                        //Left Mouse button pressed.
                        x = currentMousePos.x + 15;
                        y = currentMousePos.y - 5;

                        markerID = e.target.id.replace('Marker_', '');  
                        HideInfoBox();
                        ShowInfoBox();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //Middle Mouse button pressed.;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //Right Mouse button pressed.
                        break;
                }
            });
            /*$(this).off("click").on("click", function(e){

                x = currentMousePos.x + 15;
                y = currentMousePos.y - 5;

                markerID = e.target.id.replace('Marker_', '');  
                HideInfoBox();
                ShowInfoBox();  

            });*/
        });
    }

    var HideInfoBox = function()
    {
        $('#InfoBox .infoContainer').each(function(){
            //alert($(this).attr("class"));
            $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        });
    }

    var truncateDecimals = function (number, digits) {
        var multiplier = Math.pow(10, digits),
            adjustedNum = number * multiplier,
            truncatedNum = Math[adjustedNum < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](adjustedNum);

        return truncatedNum / multiplier;
    };


    var ShowInfoBox = function()
    {       
        var count = 0;
        $('#InfoBox .infoContainer').each(function(){
            //alert($(this).attr("class"));
            if(markerID == count)
            {
                $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
                $(this).css("top", y - 5);
                $(this).css("left", x + 15);
                $(this).css("display", "block");

                //style: 'top: '+y+'px;'+' left: '+x+'px; position: absolute;'

            }
            count++;
            if(markerID >= count){ return; }            
        });
    }

    //Loading directly...
    $("#menu img").each(function(){
        //alert("TEST");
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            //alert("TEST");
            if($(this).attr("id") == "btn1")
            {
                currentSelection = 1;
            }else if($(this).attr("id") == "btn2")
            {
                currentSelection = 2;
            }else if($(this).attr("id") == "btn3")
            {
                currentSelection = 3;
            }else if($(this).attr("id") == "btn4")
            {
                currentSelection = 4;
            }
        });
    });

    //WHY NOOOOO WOOOORKK????
    /*$( "#Marker_0" ).click(function(e) {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });*/

    //Bei jeder Mousebewegung speichern wir den aktuellen ort ab.
    $("#mapareaid").on( "mousemove", function( e ) {
        currentMousePos.x = e.pageX;
        currentMousePos.y = e.pageY;

        //console.log(currentMousePos.x);
    });

    /*$('#map').click(function(e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        alert(e.pageX - offset.left);
        alert(e.pageY - offset.top);
    });*/

    //Hier generieren wir ein neues img Tag und fügen es zu unserer MarkerBox hinzu.
    //Aufgaben: Die ID muss dringend einzigartig gestaltet werden. (Diese Änderung beinflust die positionierung nicht)
    // ^ sollte funktionieren
    $("#mapareaid").click(function(e){

        if(currentSelection != 0)
        {
            x = currentMousePos.x - halfMarkerSize;
            y = currentMousePos.y - halfMarkerSize;

            xPerc = x / $('#mapareaid').width() * 100;
            yPerc = y / $('#mapareaid').height() * 100;

            var img = $('<img />', { 
            id: 'Marker_'+markerCountID+'',
            src: 'images/'+pictureArray[currentSelection]+'',
            alt: 'Map Marker',
            style: 'top: '+truncateDecimals(yPerc,1)+'%;'+' left: '+truncateDecimals(xPerc,1)+'%; position: absolute;'
            });
            img.appendTo($('#MarkerBox'));
            markerCountID++;
            currentSelection = 0;
            markerBindClick();

            $('#InfoBox').append($('.templateinfobox').html()); 
        }

        if(currentSelection == 0)
        {
            HideInfoBox();
        }   

    });

});
```

zoom.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {

        var currentZoomLevel = 0;

        var scaleRatio = 1.2;
        var scaleDownRatio = 5/6;

        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        //Set the default map width to window.size
        $("#mapareaid").width(windowWidth);
        $("#mapareaid").height(windowHeight);

        //Set resize function...
        $(window).resize(function(){
            windowWidth = $(window).width();
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
        });

        //Set the current mapWidth/Height
        var mapWidth = $("#mapareaid").width();
        var mapHeight = $("#mapareaid").height();


        //Es gibt verschiedene möglichkeiten um eigene funktionen zu deklarieren in JQuery sowie JS.
        var markersScallingUp = function()
        {
            $("#MarkerBox img").each(function(){
                //$(this).css("transform", "scale(" + scaleMarkers+ ")" );
                //$(this).css("transform", "scale(" + scaleRatio * (currentZoomLevel + 1)+ ")" );
                $(this).css("transform", "scale(" + scaleDownRatio / (currentZoomLevel + 1)+ ")" );

                //$(this).css("top", $(this).offset().top * 1.2);
                //$(this).css("left", $(this).offset().left * 1.2);
            });
        }

        var markersScallingDown = function()
        {
            $("#MarkerBox img").each(function(){
                //$(this).css("transform", "scale(" + scaleDownRatio / (currentZoomLevel + 1)+ ")" );

                $(this).css("transform", "scale(" + scaleDownRatio / (currentZoomLevel)+ ")" );

                //$(this).css("top", $(this).offset().top / 1.2);
                //$(this).css("left", $(this).offset().left / 1.2);
            });
        }


        var infoScallingUp = function()
        {
            $("#InfoBox .infoContainer").each(function(){
                $(this).css("top", $(this).offset().top * 1.2);
                $(this).css("left", $(this).offset().left * 1.2);
            });
        }

        var infoScallingDown = function()
        {
            $("#InfoBox .infoContainer").each(function(){
                $(this).css("top", $(this).offset().top / 1.2);
                $(this).css("left", $(this).offset().left / 1.2);
            });
        }


        $(document).keydown(function(e){


            switch(e.which)
            {
                case 107:   
                    /*$('#map').elevateZoom({
                        zoomType: "inner",
                        cursor: "crosshair",
                        zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
                        zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
                    }); */
                    if(currentZoomLevel <= 8){

                        $("#mapareaid").focus();    
                        //$("#map").width(mapWidth * 1.2);
                        //$("#map").height(mapHeight * 1.2);    
                        //scaleMap *= 1.2 * (currentZoomLevel + 1)
                        //scaleMarkers /= 1.2 * (currentZoomLevel + 1)
                        $("#mapareaid").css("transform", "scale(" + scaleRatio * (currentZoomLevel + 1)+ ")" );

                        //alert(differenceX);
                        //alert(differenceX);
                        markersScallingUp();
                        //infoScallingUp();
                        //mapWidth = $("#mapareaid").width();
                        //mapHeight = $("#mapareaid").height(); 

                        //$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+100);
                        //$(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft()+(60 * currentZoomLevel));
                        currentZoomLevel++;
                    }
                break;

                case 109:   
                    if(currentZoomLevel >= 1){
                        $("#mapareaid").focus();
                        //$("#mapareaid").css("width", mapWidth / 1.2);
                        //$("#mapareaid").css("height", mapHeight / 1.2);
                        //$("#map").width(mapWidth / 1.2);
                        //$("#map").height(mapHeight / 1.2);    
                        //mapWidth = $("#mapareaid").width();
                        //mapHeight = $("#mapareaid").height(); 

                        //scaleMap /= 1.2 * (currentZoomLevel + 1)
                        //scaleMarkers *= 1.2 * (currentZoomLevel + 1)
                        $("#mapareaid").css("transform", "scale(" + scaleRatio * (currentZoomLevel)+ ")" );

                        markersScallingDown();
                        infoScallingDown();
                        //$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()-100);
                        //$(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft()-(60 * currentZoomLevel));
                        currentZoomLevel--;
                    }
                break;
            }           
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. One more question: After zoomin in, top-left part of the map is hidden. the more you zoom in, the more gets hidden and is inaccessible by scrolling. Possible solution would be to increase margin left and top from mapareaid. Maybe you know  a better solution for that?

Comment: Margins and top/left are the only solutions I came up with.

Comment: I'm using css for that now. "transform-origin: top  left;"